# Instanciar uma classe a partir do nome dela em uma string, sem usar "eval" e no Chrome (v75+)

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou precisando instanciar uma classe a partir de uma *string*.

Acontece que por alguma razão não funciona mais da forma que eu utilizava:

```
class MinhaClasse{
    meuMetodo(){
    alert('Método Funciona!');
  }
}

let nome_classe = 'MinhaClasse';
let nome_metodo = 'meuMetodo';

// var obj =  new MinhaClasse(); // instanciando diretamente funciona
var obj =  new window[nome_classe](); // instanciando por string não funciona
obj[nome_metodo]();
```

No Chrome (v75) está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: window[nome_classe] is not a constructor

```js
class MinhaClasse{
 meuMetodo(){
   alert('Método Funciona!');
  }
}

let nome_classe = 'MinhaClasse';
let nome_metodo = 'meuMetodo';

// var obj =  new MinhaClasse(); // instanciando diretamente funciona
var obj =  new window[nome_classe](); // instanciando por string não funciona
obj[nome_metodo]();
```

Também fiz um [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gosr4zdv/2/)

OBS: Observar a aplicação em navegadores atuais (Ex: Chrome v75 ou superior), pois as soluções dadas em outras respostas aqui são similares ao método que eu utilizava (descrito acima) e não funcionam nos *browsers* atuais.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 5):

De fato vi isto acontecer. Isto funcionava e não funciona mais. Não sei dizer ainda se realmente funcionava sem ser oficial ou se quebraram compatibilidade irresponsavelmente. Não é só no Chrome que mudou. Admito que a solução poderia estar sendo usada por uma falha e não por ser documentando.

Solução emergencial bem gambiarra para resolver, mas resolve mesmo e não é tão absurdo considerando que o código está no lado do cliente na maioria parte dos casos (em Node eu teria mais medo se o valor da variável usada com o nome vier de fonte externa direta ou indiretamente).

```js
class MinhaClasse{
    meuMetodo() {
        alert('Método Funciona!');
    }
}

let nome_classe = 'MinhaClasse';
let nome_metodo = 'meuMetodo';

var obj = eval("new " + nome_classe + "()");
obj[nome_metodo]();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/CreateClassByString.js).

O problema é o acesso ao objeto `window` que não tem mais acesso a todos os objetos globais como tinha antes. Mas não acontece em toda situação:

```js
function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

window["sayHello"]();
this["sayHello"]();
self["sayHello"]();
//top["sayHello"](); //tem problemas de permissão
globalThis["sayHello"]();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/CallMethodByString.js).

Então depende do contexto.

Pra falar a verdade eu não sei bem como o JS trata o construtor, este caso que está tentando fazer eu não sei se funcionou um dia porque está tentando chamar o construtor como um método normal.

Eu tentaria pelo menos sanitizar um pouco antes de usar o conteúdo. Isto torna o código muito dinâmico.

A solução ideal é não precisar disto, em muitos cenários dá para fazer sem que o nome venha de uma *string*. Os outros talvez deveria repensar se precisa disto, quase nunca precisa e é só uma tentativa preguiçosa de solução que normalmente troca robustez e performance por menos digitação e tempo de criação.

Eu ainda estou tentando achar uma solução melhor. Achei algumas que apenas escondem o `eval()`. Achei pelo menos uma que é complicada demais para usar assim. E quero achar uma resposta porque parou de funcionar.